# How Do I Select A Value After A REST Call Using AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

I have created a select box in two different ways with AngularJS. One with static options in the HTML and ng-model and one with ng-options.

Both populate the select box, however, when a value comes back from the REST API the select box stays blank.

The docs suggest tracking by id.

```
<select id="delimiter" name="delimiter" ng-model="config.delimiter"
              ng-options="option.name for option in data.availableOptions track by option.id">
</select>

 $scope.data = {
    availableOptions: [
      {id: '44', name: 'Comma'},
      {id: '9', name: 'Tab'},
      {id: '32', name: 'Space'},
      {id: '124', name: 'Pipe'},
      {id: '59', name: 'Semi-Colon'},
      {id: '58', name: 'Colon'}
    ],
    selectedOption: {id: '44', name: 'Comma'} //This allegedly sets the default value of the select in the ui
  };

//Truncated version of what happens after API call
$scope.config = $scope.result.selectedConfig;
```

The data that comes from the server contains the numbers i.e. the ids.
The config option is supposed to have the delimiter set on it and then the select box is supposed to select the correct item, but it doesn't.

However, a simple example like this DOES work at selecting the correct item so it must be something with the binding after the REST call.

```
<body ng-app ng-controller="AppCtrl">
    <div>
        <label>Delimiter</label>
        <select ng-model="mydelimiter">
            <option value="44">Comma</option>
            <option value="9">Tab</option>
            <option value="32">Space</option>
            <option value="124">Pipe</option>
            <option value="59">Semi-Colon</option>
            <option value="58">Colon</option>
        </select>
    </div>
</body>

function AppCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.mydelimiter = '59';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this is exactly what you were looking for but if you'er just trying to set a specific default value, set the model to the selectedOption

```
$scope.config = {};
$scope.data = {
        availableOptions: [
          {id: '44', name: 'Comma'},
          {id: '9', name: 'Tab'},
          {id: '32', name: 'Space'},
          {id: '124', name: 'Pipe'},
          {id: '59', name: 'Semi-Colon'},
          {id: '58', name: 'Colon'}
        ],
        selectedOption: {id: '44', name: 'Comma'}
      };
$scope.config.delimiter = $scope.data.selectedOption;
```

Or you could set it directly from the array:

```
$scope.config.delimiter = $scope.data.availableOptions[0];
```

Here's a fiddle with a working example:

http://jsfiddle.net/pkobjf3u/1/

Comment: It seems to be the binding somewhere. Maybe scopes are colliding. This example works in jsfiddle but not in my full blown application.